# Execution cost of LinqToSql custom function in query

Tags: performance, linq-to-sql

In my app I have to display some information about customers (a customer has a code and a name). One of the fields is 'display name', where

```
DisplayName = Code + " - " + Name
```

I retrieve the customer from database into a view model and set the DisplayName, like this:

```
from   customer in this.Context.Customers
select new CustomerViewModel
       {
           DisplayName = customer.Code + " - " + customer.Name
       }
```

But I would like to extract this logic into an expression or function because I use it in multiple places and if the logic changes (for example DisplayName = Name), then I have to do a lot of changes.

Therefore, I have created this function

```
Func<Customer, string> CustomerDisplayName = (c => c.Code + " - " + c.Name)
```

and use it this way:

```
from   customer in this.Context.Customers
select new CustomerViewModel
       {
           DisplayName = CustomerDisplayName(customer)
       }
```

It works fine and makes the logic reusable, but the problem is that the function cannot be parsed into an SQL statement, so LinqToSql first retrieves the data ('Code' and Name') and then executes the function for each record.

Should I be worried about performance (if I have a lot of data), and stick with the first option ? Or is it ok to use the function ?

Comment: Does the fist statement generate a good query? Does the second one generate two queries?

Comment: What does 'a lot of data mean': more than a million? Guess you anyway do not want to display all of them at the same time so I do not think you need to worry unless you get N+1 queries (profile your sql to make sure)

Comment: @Bojan: both generate a single query and in my opinion both are 'good' , but the second one has to do some extra work after the data has been retrieved from the server

Comment: @SzilardD - what does profiler say? Did you compare their execution times? Pleun is right, without the actual amount of data everything is relative. So if you don't have like > million records it doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you have the class Customer, which is a partial class (see the file yourDataClasses.designer.cs).

So, you only must to modify the file yourDataClases.cs, adding the partial class Customer and adding it the property DisplayName.

Your code in yourDataClases.cs looks like:

```
public partial class Customer
{
   public int DisplayName
   {
      get
      {
         return this.Code + " - " + this.Name;
      }
   }
}
```

Your queries would be well:

```
var res = from c in this.Context.Customers select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving not only Code and Name but the entire Customer entity with all its data. This is going to be slower. Depending on how much data is actually is (how many rows?) this might or might not be relevant from a performance standpoint. Probably, it is not, if you have less than 1000 rows.

Retrieving more columns can prevent SQL Server from using a covering index, so from this standpoint it might actually be a lot slower. If you don't have such an index anyway, the difference is only in the network transfer which is not that expensive.